# ROW_Count in VIEW

Tags: sql-server, view

I am able to run this query in SQL Server:

```
 SELECT "HIRING PIPE REQ NUMBER", 
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY "HIRING PIPE REQ NUMBER" 
           ORDER BY "HIRING PIPE REQ NUMBER") RowNumber 
FROM   DBO.TALENTDELIVERY_REQ_3FACTS
```

However, it failed when I put the code below in a `VIEW`.

```
    SELECT "HIRING PIPE REQ NUMBER", 
       ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY "HIRING PIPE REQ NUMBER" 
           ORDER BY "HIRING PIPE REQ NUMBER")AS RowNumber 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   DBO.TALENTDELIVERY_REQ_3FACTS)
```

Why does this fail in a VIEW?
How can I write the above in a VIEW?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Did you receive an error? If so, can you post it please?

Comment: You appear to have the same column in both the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses of your `OVER`. This is rarely, if ever, correct. Can you give a small example of the data in the table and what the expected result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_view1 AS     

    SELECT  [Hiring Pipe Req Number]
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY [Hiring Pipe Req Number] 
                ORDER BY 1/0
            ) AS RowNumber
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.TalentDelivery_Req_3Facts
    ) t
```